# AWS cryptographic key deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does anybody know how to delete AWS cryptographic keys without waiting the 7 day minimum waiting period for the scheduled deletion.

Comment: You can't afaik. This is designed to protect customers. Your only recourse here might be to create an AWS Support ticket but it's not clear that would be fruitful, for similar reasons.

Comment: Thank you I also thought you could not do this.